# Live Time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking to get the Live time in Excel.. All I want is E.g. If(Now()="08:00","Yes","No")

For this I would need the live time as I see Now is constant and not changing. Request your kind help if this is possible.

Comment: are you certain that Now() does not return current time?

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a coding or scripting service. You need to show your work and we can assist you. As it stands this question is off-topic.

Comment: I am not asking for any service here please. I had asked your assistance for a simple piece. If you are not able to help then please let's not be judgmental.. I have got my answer from someone who is willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Create the module and enter the code:

```
Sub freshtime()
Dim NewTime As Date
NewTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Calculate
Application.OnTime NewTime, "freshtime"
End Sub
```

[image]

Under Workbook Open enther the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
freshtime
End Sub
```

[image]

Then you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Lee. This works fantastic.. :) thank you very much once again. I have one last question please, How do I put a Login around it? E.g. In your sheet you are populating the time in "B3" so I want =IF(B3="13:37","Yes","No")... But this is not happening.. Request your help please.

Comment: Correction "Login = Logic"

Comment: Hi Lee, Any help would be really helpful on the above query please.